# How to update Metadata during playback using exoplayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, metadata, exoplayer

Im struggling abit to update the metadata coming from the notifications of a media player (using exoplayer). This causes an issue where the playlist of the songs are out of sync with the metadata in the notification and metadata in notifactions dont change straight after change is made.

I cant update metadata from a music file ( its an mp3 player app) during playback.

e.g onPrepare here being called (when song stops and plays again) makes everything work as normal/updates

```
...
    override fun onPrepareFromMediaId(
            mediaId: String,
            playWhenReady: Boolean,
            extras: Bundle?
        ) {
            exoplayer.setMediaSource(audioPlaybackRepository.getMediaSources())
            onPlaybackPrepare(audioPlaybackRepository.getMediaMetadata(mediaId))
            exoplayer.prepare()
            exoplayer.play()
        }
```

The media sources are updated in the "playlistedMediaMetadataList"  are fed to the concatenating media source. again if onPrepare is called, the bug stop

```
  override fun getMediaSources(): ConcatenatingMediaSource {
    concatenatingMediaSource.clear()
                playlistedMediaMetadataList.value?.forEach { metadata ->
                    val allTracksMediaSource =
                        ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory)
                            .createMediaSource(
                                MediaItem.fromUri(
                                    metadata.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_URI)
                                        .toUri()
                                )
                            )
                    concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(allTracksMediaSource)
                }
                return concatenatingMediaSource
            }
    }
```

How do I work around this with exoplayer? I see other media player apps do this lol

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9978#issuecomment-1060770382

here confirms that you cant't change metadata during playback:

" This is a limitation of ExoPlayer: It's not currently possible to change the **item** metadata of a currently-playing `MediaItem` - because if you try and change the whole `MediaItem` it will result in the whole `MediaSource` being re-created, and playback will not be continuous."

How do I work around this? do i switch to media 3?